# An algorithm to create clusters from data pairs in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am looking for a smart algorithm or pythonic approach to create clusters from pairs of data.

The input data is structured like this:

```
[
 (productA,ProductB),
 (productB,ProductC),
 (productC,ProductD),
 (productA,ProductD),
 (productD,ProductB),
 (productC,ProductA),

 (productE,ProductF),
 (productF,ProductG),
 (productG,ProductH),
 (productG,ProductE),
]
```

and it should be clustered to:

```
[
(productA,productB,productC,productD),
(productE,productF,productG,productH)
]
```

How can this be achieved? (The order of the products within the two clusters does not matter)

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: A *cluster* is the transitive closure over all products linked via some (directional) pair? Is the relation symmetric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/), you could build a graph and find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29):

```
import networkx as nx

data = [
 ('productA','productB'),
 ('productB','productC'),
 ('productC','productD'),
 ('productA','productD'),
 ('productD','productB'),
 ('productC','productA'),
 ('productE','productF'),
 ('productF','productG'),
 ('productG','productH'),
 ('productG','productE'),
]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(data)
for connected_component in nx.connected_components(G):
    print(connected_component)
```

yields

```
['productG', 'productF', 'productE', 'productH']
['productD', 'productC', 'productB', 'productA']
```

Comment: will try this instantly. Two things to note: 1. I love SO... always a solution to any problem, 2. I love python...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is: Quick Union algorithm.

Comment: QU requires the relation to be transitive, reflexive and symmetric. The examples don't show if the relation is symmetric.