# How to cluster pairs without networkx

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

`[['suzy', 'joe', ...], ['suzy', 'tom', ...], ['paul', 'kristy',...], ['kristy', 'griffin',...], ...]`

My desired output is to cluster the pairs into two lists:

```
['suzy', 'joe', 'tom']
['paul', 'kristy', 'griffin']
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021792/an-algorithm-to-create-clusters-from-data-pairs-in-python) that had a similar question, but it was answered with `networkx`. However, I am avoiding use of `networkx`, and have been struggling with doing this.

I tried creating a dictionary with one name, and then appending other names if they were in a pair, but it was getting messy. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are all of the lists length 2, and if so, what are the ellipses supposed to represent?

Comment: They are not length of 2, sorry, meant to signify with the ellipses that there are other elements in the list. But the pairs I am concerned with are the first and second elements of the list

Comment: Excellent, writing answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `networkx` solution you were referring to created an undirected graph, where the nodes were names and the edges were observed pairings. The clusters are then the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of the graph, which you can read off using a graph traversal algorithm (e.g. DFS, BFS).

So, you have two options:

1. Construct your own graph implementation, without using `networkx`, doing the above. Nothing I've just described are things that you can only do with `networkx`.
2. Use the [disjoint sets data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to generate the groupings. As the name suggests, we maintain a collection of disjoint sets (where a set represents a cluster of people). Whenever we see a pair, we union the clusters that the two people in the pairing originally belonged to. An implementation of union-find, as well as its application to the problem you've described, is given below:

```py
# Union-find by size.
def find(data, target):
    if data[target] < 0:
        return target
    data[target] = find(data, data[target])
    return data[target]

def union(data, first, second):
    first_root, second_root = find(data, first), find(data, second)
    if first_root == second_root:
        return False
    elif first_root < second_root:
        data[first_root] += data[second_root]
        data[second_root] = first_root
        return True
    else:
        data[second_root] += data[first_root]
        data[first_root] = second_root
        return True

data = [['suzy', 'joe'], ['suzy', 'tom'], ['paul', 'kristy'], ['kristy', 'griffin']]

# Extract list of names from data.
name_set = set()
for pair in data:
    name_set.add(pair[0])
    name_set.add(pair[1])

name_list = list(name_set)
name_table = {name: index for index, name in enumerate(name_list)}

# Find disjoint sets.
disjoint_sets = [-1] * len(name_table)
for pair in data:
    union(disjoint_sets, name_table[pair[0]], name_table[pair[1]])

# Read off disjoint sets into lists.
result = {}
for name in name_table:
    set_id = find(disjoint_sets, name_table[name])
    if set_id not in result:
        result[set_id] = []
    result[set_id].append(name)

print(list(result.values()))
```